# Editing a PDF document

Tags: pdf

I want to edit page 2 of a PDF document.  I was intending to use LibreOffice Write.  I imported the PDF document, but it will only open page 1 of 3.

I am using:
Ubuntu 18.04.1, plus all updates since then.
Libreoffice 1:6.0.7

I installed Gimp, but was unable to get it to handle the PDF doc, quite likely due to my lack of understanding of this app.

I have since asked the person, who prepared the original doc, to change it & resend it to me.

Comment: please edit your question to say which version of Ubuntu you are using and which version of LibreOffice.

Comment: try with gimp and see what happened